# Meteor update is stuck downloading packages

Tags: meteor

I am trying to update to Meteor 1.2.

But when I run Meteor update, it starts to run and get to

```
Downloading 8 packages                    -
```

And the spinner stops and its been like this for 20 minutes or so.

Ive tried quitting the process and starting it up again, and the same result.

Any suggestions on what I can try? The server seems to still start ok, but I cannot update

Here is the package list

```
3stack:accounts-password-hook          0.0.2  Overwrites Accounts.createUser to provide an afterCreateUser hook
abpetkov:switchery                     0.1.0  Switchery (official) - turns your default HTML checkbox inputs into beautiful iOS 7 style swi...
accounts-password                      1.1.1* Password support for accounts
alanning:roles                         1.2.13  Role-based authorization
aldeed:autoform                        5.3.2* Easily create forms with automatic insert and update, and automatic reactive validation.
aldeed:collection2                     2.3.3* Automatic validation of insert and update operations on the client and server.
aldeed:simple-schema                   1.3.3  A simple schema validation object with reactivity. Used by collection2 and autoform.
aramk:rrule                            2.1.0  JavaScript library for working with recurrence rules for calendar dates.
babrahams:transactions                 0.6.21* Undo/Redo stack based on transactions
benmgreene:moment-range                1.0.7  Fancy date ranges for Moment.js packaged for Meteor.
cmather:handlebars-server              2.0.0  Allows handlebars templates to be defined on the server in .handlebars files
coffeescript                           1.0.6* Javascript dialect with fewer braces and semicolons
cunneen:mailgun                        0.9.1  Easily send emails using Mailgun as your email provider.
cunneen:sendgrid                       0.9.0  Easily send emails using Sendgrid your email provider.
czbaker:apac                           0.0.3  Access to the Amazon Product Advertising API, using the NodeJS 'apac' module.
czbaker:lightbox2                      2.7.1_1  Provides the Lightbox2 JS library for Meteor.
dhtmlx:scheduler                       0.0.2  dhtmlxScheduler is an event calendar that allows adding a Google-like scheduler on a web page.
edgee:slingshot                        0.7.1  Directly post files to cloud storage services, such as AWS-S3.
email                                  1.0.6* Send email messages
francocatena:status                    1.3.0* Display the connection status between the browser and the Meteor server
gilbertwat:bootstrap3-daterangepicker  1.3.21_1  Date range picker component for Twitter Bootstrap 3
houston:admin                          2.0.3* A zero-config Meteor Admin
ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3            1.2.59+ Bootstrap-styled accounts-ui with multi-language support.
iron:router                            1.0.9  Routing specifically designed for Meteor
jonblum:jquery-cropper                 0.10.1* Fengyuan Chen's terrific jQuery plugin for cropping/zooming/rotating images, packaged for Me...
juliancwirko:s-alert                   2.4.1* Simple and fancy notifications / alerts / errors for Meteor
juliancwirko:s-alert-slide             1.1.3* Slide effect for s-alert - simple and fancy notifications / alerts for Meteor.
kadira:debug                           2.1.0* Full Stack Debugging Solution for Meteor
kevohagan:sweetalert                   0.5.0* a beautiful replacement for javascript's alert() 
meteor-platform                        1.2.2* Include a standard set of Meteor packages in your app
meteorhacks:cluster                    1.6.9  Clustering solution for Meteor with load balancing and service discovery.
meteorhacks:kadira                     2.22.0* Performance Monitoring for Meteor
meteorhacks:npm                        1.5.0  Use npm modules with your Meteor App
meteorhacks:ssr                        2.1.2  Server Side Rendering for Meteor with Blaze
meteortoys:allthings                   1.2.1* Insanely Handy Development Tools for Meteor
mquandalle:jade                        0.4.3* Jade template language
mrt:accounts-admin-ui-bootstrap-3      0.2.7+ A roles based account management system using bootstrap 3
mrt:cron                               0.0.1  Simple meteor.cron
mrt:jquery-masonry                     0.1.0  jQuery Masonry repackaged for Meteor
mrt:moment                             2.8.1  Moment.js, a JavaScript date library for dates, packaged for Meteor. See http://momentjs.com.
mrt:moment-timezone                    0.2.1  Timezone support for moment.js, packaged for Meteor. See http://momentjs.com/timezone.
multiply:iron-router-progress          1.0.1* Progressbar for iron:router
natestrauser:font-awesome              4.3.0* Latest version Font-Awesome loaded via CDN
natestrauser:select2                   3.5.1* Select2 is a jQuery based replacement for select boxes.
npm-container                          1.2.0+ Contains all your npm dependencies
praxie:canvas-to-blob                  1.1.1  JavaScript Canvas to Blob is a function to convert canvas elements into Blob objects
random                                 1.0.3* Random number generator and utilities
rcy:nouislider                         7.0.7_2  noUiSlider is a lightweight jQuery range slider plugin
reactive-var                           1.0.5* Reactive variable
reywood:publish-composite              1.3.6* Publish a set of related documents from multiple collections with a reactive join
risul:bootstrap-colorpicker            2.2.0  Bootstrap Colorpicker: http://mjolnic.com/bootstrap-colorpicker/
sacha:spin                             2.3.1  Simple spinner package for Meteor
skinnygeek1010:validate-form           0.3.0  A micro form validator
stylus                                 1.0.7* Expressive, dynamic, robust CSS
themeteorchef:bert                     1.1.0  Client-side curmudgeon for Meteor.
tsega:bootstrap3-datetimepicker        4.14.30_4  Bootstrap 3 DateTime picker from @Eonasdan, packaged for Meteor.js
twbs:bootstrap                         3.3.5  The most popular front-end framework for developing responsive, mobile first projects on the ...
woody:stripe-easy                      0.1.0+ Subsciptions with Stripe made easy for Meteor.
yogiben:pretty-email                   0.0.6  Send pretty emails
zimme:collection-timestampable         1.0.9  Add timestamps to collections
zimme:select2-bootstrap3-css           1.4.6  CSS to make Select2 fit in with Bootstrap 3
```

Comment: Can you show the results of `meteor list` in your question?

Comment: I added the results of meteor list to the answer

Answer (score 6):

It works now. I just had to wait sometime. I think the meteor package server was down. So it was just waiting. If this happens to you just wait some time and try again.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem (tried waiting or kill/re-running repeatedly) and I checked the status of the meteor package server, which was operational.  However, after I ran "meteor list" something must have changed because "meteor update" ran fine.  Could have been a coincidence but thought I'd share in case it solves the issue for someone else.

Comment: This solved it for me as well. Perhaps meteor list forces update of some package lists or something.