# Meteor: How to bypass update/upgrade

Tags: meteor, windows-10, command-prompt

Is there a way to bypass the auto update feature of Meteor?
I'm stuck with

```
   Downloading meteor-tool@1.3.0_3...        \
```

When I try to run existing project, or create a new one or simply run "meteor list",..It starts updating, downloads meteor-tool@1.3.0_3... which completes 100% and then countdown vanishes & it remains like that with the spindle rotating.

I tried waiting like mentioned at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32745811/meteor-update-is-stuck-downloading-packages)
However, nothing happens even after an hour.

Answer (score 0):

I've same error. I resolve by following steps, please try

- Download meteor installation from https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Meteor-on-Windows:-Alternate-installation
- Extract zip & Copy all tool from `.meteor/packages/meteor-tool` directory
- Go To `%AppData%/../Local/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool` or `C:\Users\<your_user_name>\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool`
- Paste inside folder (Note: If you can't copy or gives error of long path, use [RoboCopy](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17657))

Now, you can create new Meteor app.

Answer (score 0):

```
Go to project > .meteor > release
```

Change the meteor version to the current one that is installed on your system.

Consider my scenario:

```
1) System have the Meteor version 1.4.3.1 installed
2) Downloaded the todos(meteor project), developed on version 1.4.2.1
3) On running it gives similar problem
4) Changed the release version to 1.4.3.1
5) Run with command 'meteor'
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering latest Meteor **1.6** you can use below commands for your best needs

1. `meteor create . --release 1.5 --full` to create a scaffolded app.
2. `meteor create . --release 1.5 --bare` to create an empty app.

> NOTE: Instead of `--release 1.5` you could use your version which actually exists.